# Rounding a financial value of double datatype accurately to 2 decimal places in C#

Tags: c#, double, rounding

We are using these double values to represent bill amounts. I read that it is better to use 'decimal" datatype rather than double to minimize rounding errors. But Its a very big project and changing all dataypes to decimal is a herculean task. 
SO we tried Math.Round with both kinds of midpoint rounding but nothing works. There is some kind of an error. 
Is there anyway to make the rounding upto 2 decimal places accurately?

**EDIT:**
Sorry for not providing examples. The problem is once the values (totally there are 24 "double"values)get added before rounding(they were upto 15 places originally), the summed value comes to  18167.04 which is desired. But when they are rounded to 2 decimal places (using Math.Round or Math.Round with MidpointRounding), the summed value is 18167.07 (differs by .03).

Using Decimal datatype is apt for monetary calculations but since it a huge project, for now, implementing the change in datatype is a task.
No way of Rounding works. 
Is the problem really with the datatype here or because of rounding? 
WIll the same Rounding method work if decimal datatype is used?

Comment: What does not work? Examples would be appreciated.

Comment: There is plenty of 2 decimals that cannot be represented exactly by a double type so you'll get inaccuracies whatever you do.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the error you got? Please post at least the type and message of your error to allow us to help you...

Answer (score 0):

Floating point accuracy is not defined by decimal points, it is defined by significant digits. 123456789123456789.0 is no more or less accurate than 0.123456789123456789.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem that frequently occurs when dealing with financial values in programming:

**Float values do not tanslate well to decimal fractions**.

Many developers tend to think of float values as decimal fractions, because they are mostly represented by these, when converting them to strings and vice versa. *This is not the case*. Float values have their fractional part stored as **binary fraction**, as descibed [here](http://floating-point-gui.de/formats/binary/).

This makes float values (and their calulations) being slightly askew from their decimal representations.

One way out of this problem, is (as you stated) to use the data type `decimal`, that was construced to do calculations that have to translate directly to decimal fractions (as financial calculations do).

Another would be to round all results of floating point calculations, before displaying or storing them. For financial calculations one should use:

```
Math.Round([your value here], 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```

I would advise to opt for the former, whenever possible. It spares many a headache, when calculation is done. With the rounding approach, one has to take rounding errors into account at many points. It may be a big task to convert an existing project to decimal, but it will most propably pay out in the long run (if it is possible, in the fist place)...

**Regarding your edit:**

This problem arises, because the rounding errors get cumulated if you round **before** you sum. You could opt rounding the sum **after** summing up the un-rounded values. Whether you use double or decimal is irellevant in this regard, as this applies to both.

Whether this is allowed, depends on the type of financial calculation you do.
If the the summands appear in printed form on e.g. an invoice, then it is most propably **not allowed to do so**.

Comment: The program flow is such that the values get rounded to 2 decimal places (becasue that's how they are supposed to get stored in the database) and only those saved values are retrieved and summed. So i guess obviously we would be facing this error. Rounding would nt help at all at any point.

Comment: Rounding would eventually still be of some help. If your DB code is currently just trucating the numbers to 2 decimal places, this would even worsen the afforementioned cumulation of rounding errors. Excplicit rounding (eventually with MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero, to stay finacially sound) would mitigate the problem somewhat...

Comment: The DB doesnt store the truncated values but the 'rounded to 2 places' values. Actually the first time they get summed is with 4 decimal places, for the next step the summing takes with the retrieval values from the DB i.e, the ones with 2 decimal places.So when comparing both there is a deviation of say, 0.03 to 0.05 . what do u think its the way out?

Comment: None other then to prevent this loss of precision from happening by modifying the DB (getting it to store more decimal places) or the value (multiplying it by e.g. 1000 before storing and dividing it back after loading). Because: If you lose precision you **lose** precision. There is no way of getting it "magically" back, so don't lose it unless you are ready to live with the consequences.